# AngularJS: Changing Dataset in $scope With a Select control

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am just learning AngularJS and I don't even know what to Google to figure this out (the Title of this question didn't return what I was looking for).

I have a large number of records (I'll be getting them by REST from a custom SharePoint list)
that I am displaying in a table. The requirements for the project is that the user can type into an input control to filter the list (that works!!!) and ALSO use a select control to filter the recordset as well by status. With some help I have a function in my factory to return the subset of data that does not have 'Closed' as a status. I tried to use ng-model="techFilter" for the select but that broke everything.

I built a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DCfIS25B8nJD5199QBVF?p=preview).

I have a Pro subscription to egghead.io; I purchased the ng-book, AngularJS Starter, Mastering Web Applications with AngularJS, and AngularJS Directives; and, I purchased the AngularJS Kickstart course on Udemy. I REALLY am trying to learn AngularJS and I feel that I am learning AngularJS quickly because the framework is excellent but ...

I don't know how to attack this issue or even where to go in my resources for help.

Can someone point me in the right direction to wire up this select to filter the table data by status on change?

Thanks in advance to a GREAT community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be solved by combination of [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) and [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

### ng-options directive on `select` element

ng-options provide a small language, which gives developers full control over the select element.

With markup

```
<select ng-model="statusFilter" ng-options="o.value as o.text for o in options">
</select>
```

, we can separate 1) text on option 2) value of option gracefully. Just give ng-option an appropriate array, and let ng-options take care of the rest:

```
 [
   {text: 'Waiting', value: 'Waiting'},
   ...
 ];
```

### filter

Angular allow us to write our filter, but I found the basic filter is enough in most case because it's very customizable. You can pass a string, object structure or function to it, to compose whatever filter you need. In your case, an open request is a request whose status is either 'Waiting' or 'In Progress'. Just write a simple function:

```
$scope.openFilter = function(req) {
  return req.status === 'Waiting' || req.status === 'In Progress';
};
```

and use it in markup:

```
ng-repeat="request in requests | filter:openFilter"
```

Here is an updated plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/RAYF4fAgKIvcRA5tZVh0?p=preview

Comment: this is great! How about a tad more scope creep ... LOL! Is there a way to determine which is the default option (maybe in the controller). Depending on user.role, I have to set a default view (which is this filter that you built) while providing them the choice of the others. So far your plunkr is PERFECT but setting the default is critical...THANKS!!!!!

Comment: Thanks to the all mighty 2-way data binding, to set default value of a select element is just to set the model. I updated the plunkr, please visit the same link on post.

Comment: No, thanks to the all mighty Cades Kao ... you're great! Would you want to take at stab at this question (no one else has) ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23258817/angularjs-multiple-edit-forms-routing

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it, though you should refactor this. Basically I'm tying the filter to the techFilter and having the select option have a binding with techFilter as well. Refactor to have one main filtering object then have both models be properties on that filter object.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="requestsController.js"></script>
    <script src="requestsFactory.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="appITI">
    <div ng-controller="requestsController">
    Filter: <input type='text' ng-model="techFilter" />
    <br />
    <select ng-model="techFilter">
      <option>Waiting</option>
      <option>In Progress</option>
      <option selected>Open</option>
      <option>Closed</option>
      <option>All</option>
    </select>
    <table>
      <tr class="landing_data_row" 
          data-ng-repeat="request in open_requests | filter:techFilter | orderBy:sortBy:reverse">
        <td style="width:20%;">{{request.id}}</td>
        <td style="width:40%;">{{request.title}}</td>
        <td style="width:40%;">{{request.status}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

change the index.html in your plunkr to this and it will work.

Comment: same comment as above -- filtering is not enough to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have an input filter for the table, you can reuse this and connect the dropdown to this aswell.

```
<select ng-model="techFilter">
    <option>Waiting</option>
    <option>In Progress</option>
    <option selected>Open</option>
    <option>Closed</option>
    <option>All</option>
</select>
```

Here is an updated plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/OR8KRs9xXy0wlN68lbrx?p=preview

*There are several ways to solve this filtering, but this i probably the easiest one, since you are already using the `techFilter`*

Comment: but filtering isn't sufficient which is why this is driving me crazy. Filtering only works for the first two options (where status = In Progress or Waiting ) but the other three require manipulation of the $scope which I can't figure out. You notice that the initial $scope has already filtered out the Closed items from the factory/controller. So there will never be a record that has status="Closed" in the initial list. Also all is closed + opened and again required $scope manipulation. and open is Status = "Waiting" or "In Progress". I think I need to call controller functions with the select.